# React: JS TypeError: items.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, typeerror, array.prototype.map

I'm trying to display a list of Items from an API with react.

In my component class `Explore` I want to code the get and display data from the api.

While using `.map` on `items`, `this.state`, `items.state` or `items.state.results` (on the data I need from my query) I'm getting the following errors:

`Cannot read property 'map' of undefined** || **TypeError: this.state.map is not a function`

`Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): items.map is not a function`

Is the problem in the structure of the component itself? With render or the declaration of items?
Did I miss something with `this` or `this.state`? Do I need to add a function to the `.map`(or change the key)?

When I console log (in the render part of the code) `items` or `items.results` I do get the data i need before the map call.

Thank you for your help.

```js
import React, { Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import ItemDetail from './ItemDetail';

class Explore extends Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
  
      this.state = {      
        items: [],
      };
    }
      componentDidMount(){
  
          fetch('https://myapi/search/photos?query=myquery&client_id=myclientid')
          .then(res => res.json())  
          .then(json => {
              this.setState({
                isLoaded: true,
                items: json,  
              });           
          });
        }
      
        
   render() {
        var { items } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Nav to</h1>
        <div>           
            <ul> 
                {items.map(item => (
                    <li key={item.results.id}>
                        <a href={ItemDetail}>Alt: {item.results.altdescription} | </a>
                            Desc:{item.results.desc}
                    </li>))}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>       

    );
    }     
}

export default Explore;
```

Comment: Is `json` an array?

Comment: are you sure in this

``` .then(json => {
              this.setState({
                isLoaded: true,
                items: json,  
              });           
          });```


json is an array?

Comment: hi, as above, your 'items' simply isn't an array, therefor .map will not be available.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding a check to see if items is set and if its an array before calling .map on it.

On the line where you call map add `items && !!items.length && items.map...`

Also the issue could be in the format in which you are receiving data.
Try to `console.log` the `json` before calling `this.setState`

Comment: If i console log the Data received in json before calling setState:
{total: 85169, total_pages: 8517, results: Array(10)}
Data received as an object that contains the array of results i need?

Comment: Try changing ` this.setState({
                isLoaded: true,
                items: json,  
              });` to ` this.setState({
                isLoaded: true,
                items: json.results,  
              });`

Comment: this.setState({ isLoaded: true, items: json.results, }); did the trick! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Inside the render method, you have defined a state as an object
var { items } = this. state;
so the map will not work. In order to make the map work define state as
var [ items ] = this.state;